# .devcontainer Containerized environment workflow

Tags: docker, visual-studio, containers, development-environment

As an university student, I have a few programming courses each of which uses a different language and tools/extensions/libraries. On top of those I am doing hobby projects with js and rust, so to avoid having to install the necessary tools locally and have probably never use them after the courses end, I thought it would be useful to have dev env for each course plus separate setups for my personal projects.

I chose to use VSC's .devcontainers over docker's personal dev environments, since it is still beta and it seems like dev containers have better documentation and support for now.

I have some difficulties wrapping my head around the different workflows of using .devcontainers. I have read over 10 different articles / blog posts, watched a lot of YT videos and scrolled over the official docs for dev containers provided by VS code and every single resource demonstrates different ways of setting up your environment. Alas most of the focus on single container example and leave out the config of multi-container setup. Even after days of reading and testing I still have some unanswered questions:

#1 Should installation of new tools/features happen in the devcontainer.json file (add those in the "features" section) or should it happen in the Dockerfile then use that to build the environment?
This article which is the closest thing to what would be a working solution due to usage of compose instead of purely dockerfile for single container. This is the second approach https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/06/16/docker-development-container/

But the official docs shows installation tool such as azure cli via the features sections by the first approach https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_install-additional-software

Which one should be considered better approach? As far as I understand both contribute persistent changes in the environment when rebuilt and re-laucnhed.

#2 When using multiple container setup, i.e. a react based SPA with Deno runtime, custom api, postgresql db, flyway database migration and redis caching, would use 5 different containers, how would the devcontainer.json and docker-compose be separated?
In the article below, section "Tying It All Together with Remote Containers Configuration" the devcontainer.json is configured to use an additional compose file specifically for the running the environment, while the original compose file is not added to the devcontainer.json as the docker cli is used from INSIDE the dev environment to run the frontend,backend and DB containers on the host.

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/06/16/docker-development-container/

Is this considered best practice or is there way to use a single compose?

#3 When distributing my environment to e.g. a classmate for pair-programming project, I would want to have all necessary dependencies, tools, extensions, etc... as a single package without any source code, right? My understanding is that dev envs are just a prepackaged set of tools that enable developer to use the env with any source code file. If I were to share that setup w/o src code in github repo so that it can be used remotely with codespaces in the browser, would that enable the dev to start a new project in the browser?